# I have pro tool 10

Tags: pro-tools-10

I have no sound card, is it possible for proper installation without sound card, for Windows 7?

thanks
Nitin

Comment: Have you run into a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not without any sound card, but the internal/built-in sound card can/should work, given that you don't run into incompatibility problems with device drivers (I believe there have been some). Just use the official manufacturer supplied device drivers for the sound card or ASIO4ALL, (only) if the official drivers don't work.

kthxbye

Answer (score 0):

I had compatibility issues with my onboard sound card, and can vouch for ASIO4ALL as working well as a solution.
Just keep in mind that, while ASIO4ALL is running (i.e, while you're running Pro Tools) it will take the place of your onboard audio, and you probably won't have working audio on any applications that AREN'T Pro Tools.. and vice versa; if you've got other applications running that are engaging the onboard audio when ASIO4ALL starts up, you won't hear anything in Pro Tools.  At least, that's been my experience thus far.

Comment: ASIO4ALL does not "take the place" of your on-board audio. It simply provides an ASIO "bridge" to WDM devices, allowing you to access them from software which _only_ supports ASIO for all or certain features.